# A functional analysis question with respect to ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $f:[0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ has continuous derivatives, let $x_k(\cdot)$ denote the solution of the following equation:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\dot{x}=f(t,x)\sin(kt)\\
x(0)=0
\end{array} ,\right.
$$
then does the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k(t)$ exist? Why?

There is a hint that I should use weak convergence but I have no idea about it.

Comment: Recall that an ODE can be recast as a fixed point equation for an integral operator: in your case, $x(t)=\int_0^t f(s,x(s)) \sin(kx(s)) ds$. (This is basically a single Picard iteration, as is used to prove the Picard-Lindelof theorem.) Suppose $x$ and $f$ are now given continuous functions, then what is the limit as $k \to \infty$ of the right side? (If you are not familiar, the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is relevant whenever you deal with high-frequency sinusoids...)

Comment: I am sorry that I have made a mistake. It should be sinkt.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I implicitly made this same mistake in my own mind (but did not fix my notation).

Answer (score 3):

You may recast the problem as a fixed point equation:

$$x(t)=\int_0^t f(s,x(s)) \sin(ks) ds.$$

(This is the initial idea behind Picard iteration, which is the proof technique for the famous Picard-Lindelof theorem.)

Suppose $x$ is any continuous function. Then what is the limit of the right side as $k \to \infty$? You may want to look up the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.